# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes after login and load home screen

Tags: 20.04, freeze

Could you please help me to investigate what is causing frozen screen in Ubuntu 20.04? It automatically powers off the laptop in few minutes after it's hung. I'm a noob in Linux systems and I don't know how to solve it. The system allows me to login, loads fine the home screen and after several seconds it completely hangs. It's not possible to do anything, only hard power off helps.

When I load Ubuntu from the removable flash drive it works fine. For me it looks like some driver is causing this problem or hardware is broken.

When I run following command it shows information about my video adapters:

```
semshekh@semshekh:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for semshekh: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:c6500000-c651ffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:c6520000-c653ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

After I've changed the graphics option to `nomodeset` instead of `quiet splash` it works but with very very poor graphics.

Comment: If you're suspecting hardware/drivers then the logical step would be to inform about the hardware specifications. Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto the question is updated. How may I know which graphics card is actually in use right now? And disable one if possible.

Comment: Hybrid Intel+AMD graphics are notoriously harder to troubleshoot than other combinations. `nomodeset` is a temporary workaround typically used to allow installing drivers, obviously not a solution. Now, the problem: Both Intel and AMD graphics work with open-source and already installed drivers, there's nothing for the users to install. Updates, if any, come with normal kernel updates. You may try disabling one or the other if that option is available in the firmware (UEFI or BIOS). You may want to check which kernel stack you're using and try the other.

Comment: And/or try a different Ubuntu flavor like Lubuntu or Xubuntu because a 2nd Generation Intel is kinda oldish now.

Comment: @ChanganAuto it's weird but time to time it loads fine and works. There is no option in BIOS to disable or enable graphical card. Do you know how can I do that in Ubuntu settings?

Comment: Sorry, Intel+AMD is above my pay grade.